# Calling VGG many times causes an out of memory error

Tags: pytorch, vgg-net

I want to extract the VGG features of a set of images and keep them in memory in a dictionary. The dictionary ends up holding 8091 tensors each of shape (1,4096), but my machine crashes with an out of memory error after about 6% of the way. Does anybody have a clue why this is happening and how to prevent it?

In fact, this seems to be triggered by the call to VGG rather than the memory space, since storing the VGG classification is sufficient to trigger the error.

Below is the simplest code I've found to reproduce the error. Once a helper function is defined:

```
import torch, torchvision
from tqdm import tqdm
vgg = torchvision.models.vgg16(weights='DEFAULT')

def try_and_crash(gen_data):
    store_out = {}
    for i in tqdm(range(8091)):
        my_output = gen_data(torch.randn(1,3,224,224))
        store_out[i] = my_output
    return store_out
```

Calling it to quickly produce a large tensor doesn't cause a fuss

```
just_fine = try_and_crash(lambda x: torch.randn(1,4096))
```

but calling it to use vgg causes the machine to crash:

```
will_crash = try_and_crash(vgg)
```

Comment: I don't think 8091x4096 tensor equal to 32 MB because tensor may be float32 you should check it. Can you share which device are you using gpu or cpu? And default output of the vgg is not a 1x4096 vector it is a classifier which returns 1x1000 vector. Please add as much as detail.

Comment: And make sure that you add with torch.no_grad() before forwarding that tensor and make vgg to eval mode like vgg = vgg.eval().

Comment: Thanks! 1) I eyeballed the size of the tensor, but the important thing is that it fits the memory just fine, while a much smaller tensor does not. 2) I'm using cpu 3) The features are the outputs of the penultimate layer, and they are sized 1x4096. I agree that the outputs of vgg are 1x1000. 4) I do use torch.no_grad() and vgg.eval() in my code but didn't list them here as the crash happens regardless of them. Here I only included what I need to reproduce the error.

Comment: Additionally, features you put through vgg pass multiple cnn layers hence channels of the features increases that may be the problem. It is not the same when randomly collecting data and using a CNN architecture. You should see from the architecture # of features increases toward pooling layer. Check how many mb you are using by utilizing a cuda enabled gpu.

Comment: If you are extracting the whole features of an image dataset. I suggest you to first load image then extract feature using vgg and then save it into a .pt file. So that you can use another feature extraction operation easily. For your task you can prepare a custom dataset and dataloader to use these features from .pt file. This will be more efficient. If you are not doing this what is the purpose of storing all the features into a dictionary?

Comment: 1) I'm positive that the outputs of the penultimate layer of vgg are sized 1x4096, as I've verified. But that is not that relevant to the question, since the bug happens also when the full vgg model is used an the outputs are 1x1000, as you point out. 2) I can bypass the issue in a number of ways - for example, I can call vgg as many times as I want in a training loop, which is surprising - but I'm trying to understand what's going on in the snippet above because I find its behaviour very surprising.

Comment: I don't think you understand my first comment. https://towardsdatascience.com/extract-features-visualize-filters-and-feature-maps-in-vgg16-and-vgg19-cnn-models-d2da6333edd0 Check this blog post about vgg16 you should see that input image is size of 224x224x3 but after some layers the feature becomes 56*56*256 this is more features than before. I meant using vgg16 becomes a computationally expensive process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each element of the dictionary `store_out[i]` also stores the gradients that led to its computation, therefore ends up being much larger than a simple 1x4096 element tensor.

Running the code with `torch.no_grad()`, or equivalently with `torch.set_grad_enabled(False)` solves the issue. We can test it by slightly changing the helper function

```
def try_and_crash_grad(gen_data, grad_enabled):
    store_out = {}
    for i in tqdm(range(8091)):
        with torch.set_grad_enabled(grad_enabled):
            my_output = gen_data(torch.randn(1,3,224,224))
        store_out[i] = my_output
    return store_out
```

Now the following works

```
works_fine = try_and_crash_grad(vgg, False)
```

while the following throws an out of memory error

```
crashes = try_and_crash_grad(vgg, True)
```

Comment: I thought you said you run the code with torch.no_grad(). :D

Comment: I tried a bunch of stuff and I thought I did run them with torch.no_grad() too, but I must have been wrong :)